# D3.js stacked layout - for repeated X values

Tags: d3.js

Currently d3.layout.stack calculates the stacked-Y value based on the layers or series given.
Now I would like to generate stacked layout by both "X" value and by series. Anyway I am having 2-dimensional array of equal size.
For eg if my given data is,

```
var layers = [
{
"name": "apples",
"values": [
{ "x": 0, "y": 91},
{ "x": 1, "y": 290},
{ "x": 1, "y": 190},
{ "x": null, "y": null}

]
},
{

"name": "oranges",
"values": [
{ "x": 0, "y": 9},
{ "x": 1, "y": 49},
{ "x": 1, "y": 50},
{ "x": 2, "y": 220}
]
}
];
```

Here I have two layers ("apple","oranges"). My "x" values are [0,1,2];But If "X " values in the same layers looks same, then Y coordinate should be calculated based on the previous X value and series. Currently Y coordinate was calculated mapped by index.

Actual output for previous data:

```
var stacked_actual= [
{
"name": "apples",
"values": [
{ "x": 0, "y": 91,"y0":0},
{ "x": 1, "y": 290, ,"y0":0},
{ "x": 1, "y": 190, ,"y0":0},
{ "x": null, "y": null, ,"y0":0}

]
},
{

"name": "oranges",
"values": [
{ "x": 0, "y": 9,"y0":91},
{ "x": 1, "y": 49,"y0":290},
{ "x": 1, "y": 50,"y0":190},
{ "x": 2, "y": 220,"y0":0}
]
}
];
```

Expected output for previous data:

```
var stacked_expected= [
{
"name": "apples",
"values": [
{ "x": 0, "y": 91,"y0":0},
{ "x": 1, "y": 290 ,"y0":0},
{ "x": 1, "y": 190,"y0":190},
{ "x": null, "y": null ,"y0":0}

]
},
{

"name": "oranges",
"values": [
{ "x": 0, "y": 9,"y0":91},
{ "x": 1, "y": 49,"y0":480},
{ "x": 1, "y": 50,"y0":520},
{ "x": 2, "y": 220,"y0":0}
]
}
];
```

Is there any way to achieve this model?

Pls check the reference image
[enter link description here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5021700/2706213/ff7eb3c0-c48b-11e3-8cba-f63235b1a9b8.png)

Comment: Could you please post your code for how you did the stacking?

Comment: Asking code for normal stacking or else for repeated X stacking ?

Comment: repeated x stacking.  Or have you already solved your problem?